# Redirect page using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Could you help me with redirect

```
https://example.com/dev/kampaaniad/?lang=ru
```

to

```
https://example.com/dev/ru/kampaaniad/
```

---

**UPDATE:** `.htaccess` code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=ru$
RewriteRule ^dev/kampaaniad/$ /dev/ru/kampaaniad/ [QSD,R=302,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /dev/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /dev/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your tried htaccess Rules in your question as your efforts which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: In which directory is your `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, using mod_rewrite, at the *top* of your `.htaccess` file **in the document root**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=ru$
RewriteRule ^dev/kampaaniad/$ /dev/ru/kampaaniad/ [QSD,R=302,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. `^dev/kampaaniad/$`) matches against the URL-path only, which is why we need a separate *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) to match against the query string.

The `QSD` flag is required to remove the original query string from the request.

Alternatively, use backreferences to avoid repetition in the *substitution* string:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=(ru)$
RewriteRule ^(dev)/(kampaaniad/)$ /$1/%1/$2 [QSD,R=302,L]
```

The `$1` and `$2` backreferences in the *substitution* string contain the captured subgroups from the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. `dev` and `kampaaniad/` respectively). The `%1` backreference contains `ru` from the captured group in the preceding *CondPattern*.

If the `lang` URL parameter value is variable in the query string then modify the `RewriteCond` directive in the last example to read:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=([a-z]{2})$
:
```

To match any 2 character language code.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

---

**UPDATE:**

> ... redirect not working

From the look of your complete `.htaccess` file in your *updated* question it's possible that your `.htaccess` file is inside the `/dev` subdirectory? With the directives above I naturally assumed you would be putting the `.htaccess` file in the document root (parent) directory.

If the `.htaccess` file is located at `/dev/.htaccess` and not `/.htaccess` then you would need to modify the regex used in above `RewriteRule` as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=ru$
RewriteRule ^kampaaniad/$ /dev/ru/kampaaniad/ [QSD,R=302,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches the URL-path *relative* to the directory where the `.htaccess` file is located. So, `^kampaaniad/$` matches the URL `/dev/kampaaniad/` when the `.htaccess` file is in the `/dev` subdirectory.

You do not need the `<IfModule>` wrapper around these directives and you do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive, since this already occurs within the WordPress code block.

To take advantage of the `RewriteBase /dev/` directive defined later in the file, you can remove the path prefix on the *substitution* string, for example:

```
:
RewriteRule ^kampaaniad/$ ru/kampaaniad/ [QSD,R=302,L]
```

And consequently, you can also remove the path prefix from the later rewrite:

```
:
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: @MartinAbramov Please edit your question to include your complete .htaccess code (not in comments). Thanks. And what do you mean exactly by “not working”?

Comment: I mean redirect not working, I have added a screenshot of the code in question. 
Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: @MartinAbramov In what way is the redirect "not working"? Does it not redirect to `/dev/ru/kampaaniad/`? Please copy/paste the actual code (format using backtick fencing or indent by 4 spaces using the toolbar) - rather than link to a screenshot.

Comment: Btw, you do not need to wrap these directives in an `<IfModule>` container. You also do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive.

Comment: @MartinAbramov I've updated my answer in case your `.htaccess` file is in the `/dev` subdirectory and not in the document root (which I assumed). If the `.htaccess` file is located at `/dev/.htaccess` then you need to change the regex used.

Comment: Thank you so much for an answer with an explanation! It works perfect!